# iText 5.5.8 and Java 8 Arabic not shaped

Tags: java, itext, zos

I have a simple program that creates a PDF using iText 5.5.8 and Java 7 and it renders the Arabic correctly shaped. I recompiled and executed the same program using Java 8 and now the Arabic is unshaped when viewed in the PDF.
Note this job is on the mainframe z/OS, it used the ZFile class to do the read.

Here is the complete code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import com.ibm.jzos.MvsConsole;
import com.ibm.jzos.ZFile;
import com.ibm.jzos.ZFileException;
import com.ibm.jzos.ZUtil;
import com.itextpdf.text.*;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.ColumnText;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.BaseFont;
public class Simplepdf  
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ZFileException, IOException, DocumentException 
    {
        ZFile inZFile = new ZFile("//DD:INDD","rb,type=record,noseek");
        ZFile outZFile = new ZFile("//DD:OUTDD", "wb");
        BufferedReader brdr = null;
        InputStream istream = inZFile.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader rdr = new InputStreamReader(istream,"Cp420");
        brdr = new BufferedReader(rdr);
        OutputStream ostream = outZFile.getOutputStream();
        BaseFont nf = BaseFont.createFont("cour.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Float pf = Float.parseFloat("8");
        Font font = new Font(nf,pf);
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont("courbd.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        Font fontb = new Font(bf,pf);

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, ostream);
        document.open();
        ColumnText column = new ColumnText(writer.getDirectContent());
        column.setSimpleColumn(36, 770, 569, 36);
        column.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_NO_BIDI);
        String encoding = "Cp420";
        byte[] recBuf = new byte[inZFile.getLrecl()];
        int nRead;
        while((nRead = inZFile.read(recBuf)) > 0) 
        {
            String line = new String(recBuf,1,nRead-1,encoding);
            column.addElement(new Paragraph(line, font));
        }
        column.go();
        brdr.close();
        document.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `new byteّinZFile.getLrecl()ٍ`? That code line is unlikely to compile at all. What is `inZFile`? What is `brdr`?

Comment: Sorry, the download changed some characters. I have now edited the post with the complete code

Comment: The question now is clearer but that also made clearer that I am unlikely to be able to help as I have no idea about z/OS specialties. I would propose, though, that you first try to localize the code in which the problem occurs: You should try to find out whether the `ZFile.read` operation returns something different in your two scenarios; or, if it returns the same bytes, whether the `String` constructor creates different characters based on those bytes; or, if indeed iText processes those characters differently in those scenarios. Based on the result your question can be further clarified.

Comment: Will do some more investigation on the issue and update the post

Comment: I’ve notified the z/OS java team of this question.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is in the font from itext5 and not in Java

simply update your itext 5.5.8  to itext 7 implementation:

> https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.itextpdf/itext7-core/7.2.2/pom

> then edit your code:

```
  String font = "your Arabic font";
PdfFontFactory.register(font);
FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont(font, true);
PdfFont f = PdfFontFactory.createFont(fontProgram, PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H);
LanguageProcessor languageProcessor = new ArabicLigaturizer();
com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument tempPdfDoc = new 
com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument(new PdfReader(pdfFile.getPath()), TempWriter);
com.itextpdf.layout.Document TempDoc = new 
com.itextpdf.layout.Document(tempPdfDoc);
com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph paragraph0 = new 
com.itextpdf.layout.element.Paragraph(languageProcessor.process("الاستماره الالكترونية"))
            .setFont(f).setBaseDirection(BaseDirection.RIGHT_TO_LEFT)
            .setFontSize(15);
```